# About the expected value of the exponential distribution

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

The problem is from the *Intro to Probability 2nd*
[The problem is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZfMX.png)

And here is the answer.

**E[Time] =

(5 + E[stay of 2nd student] ) *

P(1st stays no more than 5 minutes)
+
(E[stay of 1st | stay of 1st  5] + E[stay of 2nd] ) *
P(1st stays more than 5 minutes)**

**using the memorylessness property of the
exponential distribution,
E[stay of 1st | stay of 1st  5] = 5 + E[stay of 1st] = 35**

I don't understand why not just E[stay of 1st] = 30 mins? Why is 5 here? I think that if the first person stays longer than 5 mins then the  effect of the being late would not be calculated.
Appreciate if you help!

Comment: Given that the first student is still around at time $5$, her **additional** stay (by memorylessness) has exponential distribution mean $30$, so her total stay has mean $35$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas I see... But there is another question: why is E[stay of 1st | stay of 1st 5] ? why not just E[stay of 1st ]? Why is conditional expected value valid? Thx!

Comment: Sorry about lateness in replying, was away. The problem is about the lateness of the second. This basically forces us to consider two cases, (i) the stay of the first was very short and (ii) the stay was at least $5$ minutes. Take a more extreme example where the second was $40$ minutes late. Then there probably would be a lot of time when no one was there, but that time counts as time from start to second person leaving.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Maybe I don't state clearly about my question. The answer is  (E[stay of 1st | stay of 1st 5] + E[stay of 2nd] ) * P(1st stays more than 5 minutes) . Why not  (E[stay of 1st] + E[stay of 2nd] ) * P(1st stays more than 5 minutes) = P( 1st stays more than 5 mins) * (30+30)?  Thanks!

Comment: What about if the second is $50$ minutes late? The analogue of your suggested formula yields a number that is very wrong.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Sorry for lateness, because I am a bit busy today. I see, do you mean that if the second guy is 40 mins late -> E[time] = P( 1st less than 40min)* ( 40 +30 ) + P( 1st more than 40 mins) *(  40 +30 +30) ? That  would be amazing! The overall expected time would be so long if the first guy stays more than 40 mins

Comment: In your post, you write in effect that if the first person stays more than $5$ minutes then  the second person being late would make no difference.  Certainly the two interviews would join seamlessly. However, the information that the interview lasted more than $5$ minutes affects the expected length of that interview. By **memorylessness** (which can be hard to grasp intuitively) given that the first interview has already lasted $5$ minutes, we can expect it to last **another** $30$, for a total conditional expectation of $35$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Yeppppppppppp!!! I understand! Memorylessness is so amazing!!! It is a bit counter-intuitive. Thanks for your help! You are so nice!